# How to compare two analog signals (piano notes)

Tags: compare, signals, signal-processing, digital, piano

I am working on a project:

A mobile application which will

1. Record a student's play (student's play from the physical piano and not the Midi/virtual piano)
2. Compare it with the master's play and then display a report.
3. The report will indicate the mismatch of tones, pace, notes, etc.

**Trial:**

I tried to convert the analog signals (student's play) into the digital signals and then start comparing them.

But it didn't work well. The comparison didn't work as expected. It couldn't take multi variables needed for the report and thus gave a wrong report.

Any other ideas how to do the above task?

Comment: Can anyone give a little hint? It will help me to move forward.

Comment: It will be a very complex project worthy of a PHD. I can give you a rough outline of how I'd approach it (which doesn't mean it's the only way or even a way that will be guaranteed to work). Assuming both clips are played on instruments with fixed pitch (excludes violin, etc). Start by converting the signals into spectrograms. Align the spectrograms temporally (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation, etc). Analyze the warping curve to give it a score. Analyze the amplitude differences of the aligned clips to also give it a score.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus Thanks. What if I only consider tempo and the correctness of the notes (volume)?

Comment: tempo is reflected in the warping curve and volume is the same as log amplitude.